# i need to know the difference between translational mass and rotational mass

Tags: physics, ansys

Reading the results of numerical modal analysis using ANSYS workbench, there were two types of masses , translational mass and rotational mass, I wonder if any body knows the physical difference between them ?

Comment: try asking at physics.se ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global mass matrix can be partitioned in a translational and a rotational mass matrix. The rotational mass matrix contains the mass moments of inertia.